# How to generate regular expression for language of regular expressions?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

Alphabets = $\{0, 1, \epsilon, \emptyset, [, ], \cup, \circ, \star\}$
where $\circ$ stands for concatenation, $\star$ is kleene star, $\epsilon$ is empty string, $[$ and $]$ are brackets to be used for language to be generated.
Only those Regular Expressions to be considered which don't have nested brackets $[[]]$.

How to handle $[ \ ]$ in this problem ?
An expression can be -
$[1\star\star \cup 0] \cup [\epsilon \cup 1 \circ 0] \cup 1\star$

What would be a regular expression that describes the language of such regular expressions?

Edit -

I want to come up with Regular Expression for the **Language of Regular Expressions** as show in example above. One thing though is that the regular expression should not generate such expressions which contains nested bracket ( we don't want to consider that ) so $[1 \cup [0 \cup \epsilon]]$ is not valid and should not be generated by the Regular Expression.
What I have done and my understanding so far - 
For single character Regular Expression would be $(0 \cup 1 \cup \epsilon \cup \phi)$. Be reminded that we are creating regular expression for Language of Regular Expressions. So $(0 \cup 1 \cup \epsilon \cup \phi)$ accepts these regular expressions - $0$ , $1$ , $\epsilon$ , $\phi$.

For $0\star\star$ kind of expressions - $(0 \cup 1 \cup \epsilon \cup \phi)\star^{\star}$ should work.

For $0\star\star \cup 1\star$ types we can have $(0 \cup 1 \cup \epsilon \cup \phi)\star^{\star} \bigcup\ (0 \cup 1 \cup \epsilon \cup \phi)\star^{\star}$

I am getting feeling that somewhere I need to use recursion. So I how to handle bracket $[ ]$ in this case ? How to accept those expressions which have brackets and they are not nested ?
If anyone can give me logic or direction to solve this problem competely that will also be ok.

Comment: If you don't want to generate nested brackets, how will you ever describe all regular expressions?

Comment: A Regular Expression cannot handle nested brackets. Here I have to come up with a regular expression that accepts a language of regular expressions. So you see $[0+1]^{\star}$ is a regular expression that should be generated by the Regular Expression.

Comment: Did you consider **postfix** expressions? They are bracket-free. Rather than $S+T$ write $ST+$, etcetera.

Comment: This is not about POSTFIX notations. I have to create a Regular Expression, that accepts regular expressions of any form but without nested brackets. $[0+1]^{\star} \cup [01]^{\star}$ is accepted as this does not have nested brackets but $[0+[01]^{\star}]^{\star}$ is not accepted because it has nested brackets.

Comment: OK, in that case change your third sentence to: what would be a regular expression that describes the language of *such* regular expressions? By the way, I suggest you try finding an expression for r.e.s with one pair of brackets first, then two pairs of brackets, then use a Kleene star to handle an arbitrary number of pairs of brackets.

Comment: I have the strong feeling that "regular expressions without nested brackets" are not regular expressions at all, but a properly weaker formalism.

Comment: I want to create a regular expression that accepts a language of regular expressions and this language of regular expressions should not contain  nested brackets. Its the demand of question you can say.

Comment: Just for the record: using regular expressions with limited nesting depth isn't good enough: they cannot describe all regular languages, [as shown in 1963](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_height_problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider first a simpler situation, in which you have only one "atom" $a$, only one binary operator $\circ$, and no unary operator. The expressions you are captured by
$$
X (\circ X)^*, \quad X = a+[a(\circ a)^*].
$$
In order to get an actual regular expression, substitute $X$ (surrounded by parentheses) in the left expression.

Adding a postfix operation $\star$ isn't too difficult:
$$
Y (\circ Y)^*, \quad Y = A+[A(\circ A)^*]\star^*, \quad A= a\star^*.
$$

In order to get an actual regular expression, first substitute $A$ into $Y$, then $Y$ into the leftmost expression.

Finally, the expression you are looking for only differs in that there are several "atoms" and several binary operations:
$$
Z (\circ Z)^*, \quad Z = B+[B((\cup + \circ) B)^*]\star^*, \quad B= (0+1+\underline{\epsilon}+\underline{\emptyset})\star^*.
$$
Here $\underline{\epsilon},\underline{\emptyset}$ are the versions in your alphabet.

Comment: I must say beautiful and very structured explanation ( solution ) it is. I am still trying to get some bad cases if I will come up with something I ll let you know.

Comment: Is this solution correct or near correct ? I came up with this one.
$(RR\star^{*}(\cup + \circ)RR\star^{*}+[RR\star^{*}(\cup + \circ)RR\star^{*}])((\cup + \circ)(RR\star^{*}(\cup + \circ)RR\star^{*} + [RR\star^{*}(\cup + \circ)RR\star^{*}]))^{*}\ where\ R =(0\cup1\cup\epsilon\cup\phi)$

Comment: I might be missing something, but can this expression generate, for example, $0$?

Comment: I think yes by converting first $R$ into $0$. Other $R$s can be expanded to $\epsilon$.